# Is it possible to have nonzero limit for Taylor expansion's remainder?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Suppose $f(x)$ has derivatives of all orders, then the remainder $R_n(x)$ of Taylor/Maclaurin formula can be written for any $n$ in the form:
$$R_n(x)=f(x)-[f(a)+(x-a)\frac{f^{(1)}(a)}{1!}+(x-a)^2\frac{f^{(2)}(a)}{2!}+...+(x-a)^n\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}]$$

if $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}R_n(x)=0$, then an expansion of $f(x)$ into an infinite Taylor power series is obtained

---

[Question]: What would happen if for example, $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}R_n(x)=\epsilon$, or any nonzero constant ? Is it even possible ? Is there any example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $a = 0$ and $f$ is this [non-analytic smooth function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#An_example_function):
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
e^{-1/x} & \text{ if $x > 0$} \\
0 & \text{ if $x \leq 0$} \\
\end{cases}$$

Then $f(0) = 0$, and one can show via induction that $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for all $n$. Hence the remainder $R_n(x)$ is simply $f(x)$ for all $n$, and so $\lim_{n \to \infty}R_n(x) = f(x)$, which is nonzero for any $x > 0$.